# How to make a FOR XML AUTO output of an Inner Joined SELECT output both tables to their own respective Elements?

Tags: xml, t-sql, stored-procedures, inner-join, for-xml

I'm attempting to create a stored proc that uses a BIT variable to print out one of 2 possible FOR XML results of a Inner joined Select statement. Here is the current form of the proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CustomerAddress_Get
@IsAuto BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
--@IsAuto If's
IF (@IsAuto == 0)
    BEGIN

    SELECT LEFT(GivenName,1), Surname, DOB, AccountId, Type, Balance FROM Custs
    INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts 
    ON Accounts.CustNo = Custs.CustNo
    FOR XML RAW ('CustomerAccount'), ELEMENTS, ROOT('CustomerAccountDetails')

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN

    SELECT LEFT(GivenName,1), Surname, DOB, AccountId, Type, Balance FROM Custs Customer
    INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts Account
    ON Account.CustNo = Customer.CustNo
    FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT

    END
END;
```

And the code I'm specifically trying to alter to output Accounts and Customers to their own Elements in the XML AUTO Output is this:

```
SELECT LEFT(GivenName,1), Surname, DOB, AccountId, Type, Balance FROM Custs
INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts 
ON Accounts.CustNo = Custs.CustNo
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT
```

An example of my current XML output from my Else SELECT...FOR AUTO; statement is thus:

```
<Customer>D<Surname>Grayson</Surname><DOB>1940-04-01T00:00:00</DOB><Account><AccountId>159</AccountId><Type>Chequing</Type><Balance>0.0000</Balance></Account><Account><AccountId>160</AccountId><Type>Savings </Type><Balance>500.0000</Balance></Account></Customer>
```

However, I require it to be more like this:

```
<cu>
<FirstName>Catherine</FirstName>
<LastName>Abel</LastName>
<EmailAddress>catherine0@adventure-works.com</EmailAddress>
<ca>
<AddressType>Main Office</AddressType>
<ad>
  <City>Van Nuys</City>
  <StateProvince>California</StateProvince>
</ad>
```

Which is what I believed the FOR XML AUTO was for, however it doesn't seem to be actually formatting the resulting XML.

Now, my question relative to this is how exactly can I make the this SELECT put the Customer (GivenName, Surname, and DOB/DateOfBirth) and Accounts (AccountId, Type, and Balance) their own respective details in their own Elements in the XML AUTO output?

Comment: The title of your query sounds like *I want to get two different XML formats of the same query depending on a `BIT` paramter. How can I achieve this?* But the question at the end sounds like *The output of my `FOR XML AUTO` should wrap the two sources in parent elements. How can I achieve this?* These are two questions actually. Please clearify...

Comment: @Shnugo My apologies if my question was confusing, my question is focused entirely upon the ELSE Select statement, which would be the "How can I get the output of my FOR XML AUTO to wrap two sources in parent elements" question. I provided the rest, including my overall goal, for context in case it would be necessary to change the structure of the stored procedure to facilitate this. I know I simply need to change the bit to 1 or 0 to achieve either the If (@IsAuto = 0) or the Else, so that is not my question.

Comment: Please provide edit your question and provide an example of the XML how it looks at the moment and another example, how you want it to look...

Comment: @Shnugo I've added the current XML output of the proc, and an example of how I need it to look.

Comment: The `AUTO` means, that SQL-Server chooses the format for you. If you want to control this, you must use `FOR XML PATH` and specify the output yourself. Is this an option?

Comment: See my update, if this does not solve your issue, please ensure, that the given data and the examples match together, state your tables definition and provide sample data with expected output fitting to this data.

Comment: @Shnugo It is not possible to use Path as far as I can tell, unfortunately. The specifications are that " The structure must be automatically formatted,
The account details are to be added to an element called 'Account',
and that the Customer details are added to an element called 'Customer', all column details are added in separate elements, and that we use a non-named root node".

Comment: Is this for one customer only? If not: How is the Address bount to the customer if there are many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to the question according to your title using a dynamically created statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CustomerAddress_Get
@IsAuto BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
--@IsAuto If's
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    N'SELECT LEFT(GivenName,1), Surname, DOB, AccountId, Type, Balance FROM Custs
    INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts 
    ON Accounts.CustNo = Custs.CustNo
    FOR XML '
);

IF @IsAuto = 0
    SET @cmd=@cmd+N'RAW (''CustomerAccount''), ELEMENTS, ROOT(''CustomerAccountDetails'')';
ELSE
    SET @cmd=@cmd+N'AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT';

EXEC (@cmd);
END;
```

### UPDATE: Your second question

If you use `FOR XML PATH` you can control the final format of your XML

Without knowing your tables it's hard to suggest the right solution (the given data and examples do not match!), but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(cu.GivenName,1) AS [cu/FirstLetter]
      ,cu.GivenName AS [cu/FirstName]
      ,cu.Surname AS [cu/LastName]
      ,cu.DOB AS [cu/Birthdate]
      ,cu.City AS [ad/City]
      ,cu.StateProvinve AS [ad/StateProvince]
      ,ac.AccountId AS [ac/AccountId]
      ,ac.Type AS [ac/Type]
      ,Balance AS [ac/Balance] 
FROM Custs AS cu
INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts AS ac
ON ac.CustNo = cu.CustNo
FOR XML PATH('Customer'),ROOT('root')
```

In this case I'd suggest not to use the approach with dynamically created SQL as given above, but to stick to your existing `IF ... ELSE ...`

### UPDATE 2: Sub-select instead of join

You might try something like this. The code will create the embedded XML as sub-select:

```
SELECT Custs.*
     ,(
        SELECT Accounts.* 
        FROM dbo.Accounts 
        WHERE Accounts.CustNo = Custs.CustNo
        FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS,TYPE
      ) AS [ad]
FROM Custs AS [cu]
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT
```

Comment: I know that the XML output data and the given example doesn't match, I simply need it to be similar in structure to the example. I'm not entirely sure how the output is supposed to look, only that Account and Customer are supposed to be separate and that the example is how XML AUTO is supposed to format.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Shnugo, I believe I may have mis-interpreted the specifications to be much harder than they are intended to be and realized I'd already completed it.

Comment: @Jaeriko Great, It's always good if one finds out, that life is simple as one've thought :-) Happy Coding!